# Regex, extracting numbered lists (multi lines)

Tags: c#, regex

I got the following text:

```
1. This is a text
where each item can span over multiple lines
2. that I want to
extract each seperate
item from
3. How can I do that?
```

I tried this regex in refiddle:

```
/([\d]+\.)(.*)/s
```

But I'm unsure of if it's greedy (just returning one item) or if it extracts all items. But when I tried it in C# the regex didn't match anything.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

It's gready but didn't work since `\s` doesn't seem to work in .NET. I can fix the line endings (since they are stripped) myself. But how do I make the regex to not be greedy? Is it possible to say something like

*Match the digits+dot and then take everything but the next digits+dot*?

Comment: It largely depends on how you have tried. Show us your code, please.

Comment: I've tried with and without the `MultiLine` option. I've tried both with `Replace()` (using the callback overload) and with `Match()` and all combinations in between.

Comment: I like regexlib.net with its regex tester, in order to test some regex

Comment: `RegexOptions.Singleline` do the thing with `([\d]+\.)(.*)` but it doesnot add space between words in different lines

Comment: @jgauffin http://ideone.com/U6YMW2 your pattern does its job very well.

Comment: @PLB: Look again. You only print the first line of each item...

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly: No it do not. It's greedy. Everything goes in one match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string input = @"1. This is a text
    where each item can span over multiple lines
    2. that I want to
    extract each seperate
    item from
    3. How can I do that?";
string pattern = @"([\d]+\. )(.*?)(?=([\d]+\.)|($))";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```